# Populating a custom attribute via csv

Tags: powershell

can someone who knows more than powershell than I please point me in the right direction?
I have created a custom attribute called salesforcerole. I now want to populate that attribute from csv. I have a csv with users sam account name in 1st column and the salesforcerole in the 2nd column.
I try and run this

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
$Attribcsv = Import-csv “c:\\scripts\\sf\\beauty.csv”

ForEach ($User in $Attribcsv)
{
  Get-ADUser -Identity $User.samAccountName | set-ADUser -Add @{SalesforceRole="Beauty"}
}
```

Hoping to populate the attribute for the listed users with "Beauty", but I keep getting this error

```
Get-ADUser : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Identity'. The Identity property on the argument is null or empty.
At line:5 char:22
+ Get-ADUser -Identity $User.samAccountName | set-ADUser -Add @{Salesfo ...
+                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Get-ADUser], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationError,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.GetADUser
```

can anyone please advise? Much appreciated

Comment: Does the CSV file have a header row? A top row that just lists the column names, eg. `samAccountName,SalesforceRole`

Comment: yes, 1st column has a header called SamAccountName and the 2nd column has a header of the name of the custom attribute SalesforceRole

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to set the delimiter parameter on the Import-Csv command (with the delimiter used in the csv file):

for example (if comma is used as delimiter in your csv):

```
$Attribcsv = Import-Csv -Path "c:\scripts\sf\beauty.csv" -Delimiter ","
```